# Alternative to @reboot for busybox crond?

Tags: cron, busybox

I'm trying to run a script at startup using busybox, but I've read that @reboot isn't supported with my version of cron. I need to use cron for this rather than running the script some other way. Is there an alternative solution to getting it to run at startup with crond and crontab?

Answer (score 0):

`@reboot` can be implemented in Busybox by using `/etc/init.d/local` (& placing the scripts in `/etc/local.d`).

It can also be done by [altering `/etc/init.d/crond`](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/271/commits/360f82c783df03090de9895245afe1d3111c6305).